# HackerRank Sales by Match

Tags: java, performance, beginner

This is my first post. I'm switching from Python to Java and I've been practicing on `HackerRank` for some time. Today I solved this problem in which you have to count the pairs of occurrences of the numbers in the ArrayList, symbolizing socks, and you have to count the pairs.

Can this be optimized in any way? Maybe I'm too used to Dictionaries' methods and syntax in Python. Anyway, any feedback is appreciated.

```java
public static int countPairs() {

    HashMap<Integer,Integer> mapa = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> list=new ArrayList<Integer>();

    list.add(10);
    list.add(20);
    list.add(20);
    list.add(10);
    list.add(10);
    list.add(30);
    list.add(50);
    list.add(10);
    list.add(20);

    int pairs=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (!mapa.containsKey(list.get(i))) {
            mapa.put(list.get(i), 1);
        } else {
            mapa.replace(list.get(i), mapa.get(list.get(i))+1);
        }
    }

    int whole;
    for (Integer key : mapa.keySet()) {
        whole = (int)mapa.get(key)/2;
        pairs=pairs+whole;
    }
    return pairs;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prefer assigning variables to the most generally applicable type. If it doesn't matter what kind of list you have, use `List`. If it doesn't matter what kind of map you have, use `Map`.

Use whitespace consistently. `=`, `+`, and `/` should have whitespace on both sides.

Code doesn't need to declare the generic type on the right hand side of an assignment. The compiler will infer it from what is declared on the left hand side. Use `<>` instead.

`Arrays.asList()` is probably easier to read than adding multiple values to the list. Do note that this type of list is fixed size after it is created.

`list` is not very descriptive, nor is `mapa`. Descriptive names are very important.

It would be preferable for the code to use an enhanced for loop. Iterators are more efficient at going over some List types than calling `get()`. They are also easier to read.

The if-else block could be replaced with a getOrDefault() call followed by a put.

It would be preferable to iterate over the mapa values instead of keys. The keys don't matter except to separate out the counts.

The declaration of pairs belongs closer to where it's actually used.

`whole` can be declared inside the loop.

All the math can be done on one line inside the second loop.

The logic can also be done more efficiently using a Set. Iterate over each sock. If it's in the set, remove it and increase the pair count. If it's not in the set, add it.

If you made all these changes, your code might look like:

```
public static int countPairs() {
    Map<Integer, Integer> sockCounts = new HashMap<>();
    List<Integer> sockIds = Arrays.asList(10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20);

    for (int sockId : sockIds) {
        int currentCount = sockCounts.getOrDefault(sockId, 0);
        sockCounts.put(sockId, currentCount + 1);
    }

    int pairs = 0;
    for (int count : sockCounts.values()) {
        pairs += (count / 2);
    }
    return pairs;
}

public static int countPairsWithSet() {
    List<Integer> sockIds = Arrays.asList(10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20);
    Set<Integer> unmatchedSocks = new HashSet<>();

    int pairs = 0;
    for (int sockId : sockIds) {
        if (unmatchedSocks.contains(sockId)) {
            unmatchedSocks.remove(sockId);
            pairs++;
        } else {
            unmatchedSocks.add(sockId);
        }
    }
    return pairs;
}
```

Comment: You can also take advantage of the return value of `add` to optimize runtime performance slightly at the cost of readability: `if (!unmatchedSocks.add(sockId)) { unmatchedSocks.remove(sockId); pairs++; }` Experienced developers will recognize that, but it will probably confuse junior developers.

Answer (score 4):

I noticed in your code the following definitions:

```
HashMap<Integer,Integer> mapa = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> list=new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

When it is possible it is better to use an interface than a class implementing the interface like below:

```
Map<Integer,Integer> mapa = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
List<Integer> list=new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

So for example if you want to use `TreeMap` instead of `HashMap` you can just declare `Map<Integer,Integer> mapa = new TreeMap<Integer,Integer>();` without affecting the rest of the codebase.

In the line `whole = (int)mapa.get(key)/2;` you can erase the cast to `int`, I think you added this because related to your Python programming practice.

Answer (score 3):

In your for-loop, you basically mimic `Map.computeIfAbsent`. For a given int `n`, you can use

```
map.computeIfAbsent(n, ignore -> 0);
```

to return 0 when the key is not present, and thus

```
map.put(n, map.computeIfAbsent(n, ignore -> 0) + 1);
```

as your calculation.

Note that `ignore -> 0` is a lambda of the signature `Function<Integer, Integer>`, which does not use its input parameter. Therefore I named it "ignore".

Comment: Not sure if this is allowed in java, but the traditional name for a lambda parameter you ignore is `_`, as in `_ -> 0`

Comment: Use `putIfAbsent` to avoid the lambda. Or, better, `getOrDefault` as the returned value is `put` in the map anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8 introduced [Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html): have a look at them! Despite a somewhat verbose syntax, you might find things you're more familiar with in Python.

You'll probably be interested in the [groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.stream.Collector)) Collector. And in [Map#replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#replaceAll(java.util.function.BiFunction)).